# Visual Studio 2010, xsl:fo intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xsl-fo

Is there any way to activate intellisense for xsl:fo documents? Writting all that tags is horrible, and I couldn't find any solution on my own.
I know that I could install another editor, but I've already get used to VS.

Comment: By "xsl:fo documents", do you mean XSLT stylesheets that produce XSL-FO markup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the FO schema/DTD C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Xml\Schemas. It is located at the link in the page http://www.xmlpdf.com/faq.html#13. This will allow you to add intellisense for FO markup.

Comment: The link no longer works (not surprising after all this time). I have implemented this fix using the XSD from https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xmlgraphics/fop/trunk/src/foschema/fop.xsd

Comment: Thanks Duncan, helped me as well. FYI, no need to restart Visual Studio.